# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime.nullSafeGet

Tags: hibernate, jodatime

I'm trying to use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html) - 2.1 with Hibernate [4.2.0.CR1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate4/4.2.0.CR1/hibernate-release-4.2.0.CR1.zip/download). I have some date-time fields in some entity classes like,

```
@Column(name = "DISCOUNT_START_DATE")
@Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime discountStartDate;
```

The annotation `Type` is a type of `org.hibernate.annotations.Type`. I'm getting the following exception with this.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime.nullSafeGet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;[Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:127)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:106)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2903)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1668)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1600)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1500)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:712)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:940)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1246)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
at dao.DiscountDAO.getList(DiscountDAO.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy49.getList(Unknown Source)
at controller.DiscountController.showForm(DiscountController.java:207)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

it was mentioned in some answers that it requires [`joda-time-hibernate-1.3`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time-hibernate/1.3/joda-time-hibernate-1.3-dist.zip/download) (not older) on the class-path but doing so also didn't work for me.

Does Hibernate really **not** work with `org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to [this document](http://www.joda.org/joda-time-hibernate/), the joda-time requires `Hibernate 3.6`, and is up to date for `Hibernate 4+` .
But you can use user types from Jadira framework.

User type in this case is

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
```

and can be found in Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
   <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0.CR1</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven repo search result : [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.jadira.usertype%22%20AND%20a%3a%22usertype.core%22)

Comment: The approach with `org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime"` which works for me is by using `usertype.jodatime-2.0.1.jar`, `usertype.spi-2.0.jar` and `joda-time-2.1.jar`. Is that approach with `org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime` really not compatible with Hibernate 4.x?

Comment: I use `org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime` in the place of `org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime` for Hibernate 4.x with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the same error with Hibernate 4.2.0.CR1.  But by changing the version to 3.6.8.Final, the issue got resolved.

Comment: I insisted upon using the latest version of Hibernate 4.2.0 CR1 which works with `org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime`. Thanks for the answer.