# Joda time Hibernate : PersistentLocalDateTime.nullSafeGet

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime

Upgraded a legacy application from older versions to later versions.

Upgraded joda time to 2.1 and joda-time-hibernate to 1.3 and Hibernate 4.

I think, joda-time-hibernate 1.3 is not compatible with Hibernate4. So, what other jar I can use inorder to have same behaviour without changing anythine in the code?

When I login, I am getting the following error as root cause,

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime.nullSafeGet
```

my role.hbm has the following configs related to time:

```
<property name="insertTime" type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalDateTime" column="INSERTTIME"/>
<property name="updateTime" type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalDateTime" column="UPDATETIME"/>
```

when I debug, user roles are getting to null! how to resolve this issue. Any suggestion is appreciated!

following is full stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/tsl] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime.nullSafeGet(Ljava/sql/ResultSet;[Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2873)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1668)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1600)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1500)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:712)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:940)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2228)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1804)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:549)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$1.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.isEmpty(PersistentSet.java:163)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.isEmpty(Collections.java:999)
    at ca.ups.tundra.security.TundraAuthenticationProvider.rolesToAuthorities(TundraAuthenticationProvider.java:34)
    at ca.ups.tundra.security.TundraAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(TundraAuthenticationProvider.java:84)
    at ca.ups.tundra.security.TundraAuthenticationProvider$$FastClassByCGLIB$$e6ded9b.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at ca.ups.tundra.security.TundraAuthenticationProvider$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$82804242.authenticate(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: You may want to go with the UserType project. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14900875/1037210) question. I think, the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900875/java-lang-abstractmethoderror-org-joda-time-contrib-hibernate-persistentdatetim#comment20915797_14903740) below the accepted answer may reflect the jar files you need to download. It is an incompatible change in Joda-time-hibernate that doesn't function with Hibernate 4.x.

Comment: I was using usertype.core but was failing! your comment and redirect to question did helped! thanks!